# Ruby routes not working?

Tags: ruby, sql-server, routes

Today I started working on my first Ruby project. The goal is to convert my personal site to Ruby so I can use some open source projects to add a contact form. Anyway, I decided to copy all of the HTML from the static site and just put it into a view called index.html.erb. The problem is that I don't know how to route it as the root of the site. The route I'm using in my routes file is:

> "root to: pages#index" (someone looked at my code and suggested it, I haven't looked into routes yet much)

When I rails server to the site I get this error message: "Routing Error - uninitialized constant PagesController." This leads me to believe that I also need a controller, but I don't know what action to put in it. Sorry if this is a noobish question, but I've only been learning Ruby for about a week. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your console inside your project folder:

```
rails generate controller FooBar baz qux
```

where FooBar is the name of your controller and baz and qux are the actions inside that controller.

-

Then goto

> config/routes.rb

and add this line:

```
root to: 'foobar#home'
match '/foobar',    to: 'foobar#baz'
```

where foobar is the controller and baz is the action inside the controller